# Get single row from MSSQL query without while loop

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

For some further operations, I need to quickly get the MAX(UserId) of a table containing users. Is it safe to do the following?

```
$max_user = sqlsrv_fetch_array(sqlsrv_query($connection, "SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM z_users;"))[0];
```

I mean without using a loop like `while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

Also, I noticed that using the code I wrote above returns an array with two elements: one with index 0 and another without an index but with the same value.

Like `Array ( [0] => 1211 [] => 1211 )`

Why is this happening?

Comment: You still need to use `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` to only get 1 element in your array (though you'd need to give a name to your column) because the default is `SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH` which has both an associative and a numeric representation of the result in the same array. It would be problematic if you were trying to get the top 1 result from a large set of results as it would read the entire result set in memory and then get the first result. In this particular case you are only ever going to get one row in the result set so it should be fine to do it this way

Comment: That explains why the second element didn't have an index, because I hadn't named the MAX() column... That makes sense! I suppose that forming the query like this `SELECT MAX(UserID) AS something` would fix that! Thank you for your reply. It really helped me a lot!

Comment: `Is it safe to do the following?` FWIW, I'm not a php guy, but ... would ask why are you retrieving the max ID?  IF the reason is that you're trying to obtain the ID of a newly inserted record - *don't do it that way* - because it's not thread safe. Multiple threads can obtain the same number. Use `scope_identity()` instead.

Comment: @SOS no, I don't need to determine a newly inserted user's ID. Exactly the opposite, I want to store a new user, and need the last user's ID, to do a MAX() + 1... The ID field isn't set to autonumber... Don't blame me for that. I found the table like that by someone else.

Comment: @FayeD - Okay, but it still suffers from the same problem. Say multiple threads ask for the MAX at the exact same time. Both threads will get back the same value: `5`. Then they both add +1 and try and insert the same new UserID value: `6` . Classic [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Comment: This will be used within a WooCommerce webhook that will be syncing an e-shop's new orders to the merchant desktop app that's responsible for issuing the vouchers, keeping track of the inventory, etc... I can't imagine two people ordering at the exact same moment, plus WooCommerce (I think) puts webhook tasks in a queue. In any case, how does this scope_identity() work? I'm not into MS-SQL, it's one of my first times dealing with it...

Comment: Well, personally I wouldn't want to depend on that because race conditions are notoriously hard to reproduce and track down ;-)  But perhaps the column is marked as PK and prevents duplicates? i.e. So any attempt to insert the same Id would just fail? `how does this scope_identity() work`? That was posted before I realized it's not an `identity` column, so it's not even an option. See [scope_identity()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql). In short: a row is inserted into a table with an identity column, scope_identity() returns the generated id.

Comment: I just checked, and the UserId column is just set as int. `Identity specification` and `Is Identity` options are set to `No`. Maybe poor design, but I have to work with what I have at hand... Oh well... I'll have to depend Woo's webhook queuing at least...

Comment: If you really must use SELECT MAX(ID) you need some kind of lock to ensure multiple threads don't generate the same ID value. Also, check to see if the UserId column is marked as a PRIMARY KEY. If it is, that would at least prevent the insertion of duplicate values if multiple threads ever generated the same id, which is good. While you may think it's unlikely, in a multiple threaded app it can - and does - happen.  See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=196a5e3d031ab1fdae127916418e89f6).